# Update nested arrays in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a document that resembles the following structure, and I'd like to update property3 using mongoosejs. I have tried:

```
mongoose.model('someObject').update({"_id":"52817b7be2d14af309000005",
"array1._id":"52817b7be2d14af309000006", 
"array2._id":"52817b7be2d14af309000007"}, {"$set":{"array2.$.property3":false}})
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there an official way to do this? Additionally is there a clean way to dynamically nest this using expressjs without custom routes? eg.

```
'put someobject[52817b7be2d14af309000005].array1[52817b7be2d14af309000006]
.array2[52817b7be2d14af309000007].property3 = false'
```

Here's the collection:

```
someObject:{
  property1:true,
  array1:[
    property2: true,
    array2:[
      property3: true
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Your collection seems not to be valid. [] represents array, but you have object attributes there. Correct collection would be:

```
{
    "property1": true,
    "array1": {
        "property2": true,
        "array2": {
            "property3": true
        }
    }
}
```